# Зум фотографии в pop up окне

Tags: javascript, html, popup, zoom

У меня есть pop up окно с картинкой. Реализовано с помощью плагина Chocolat
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Задача заключается в том чтобы сделать зум этой картинки

Пробовал добавлять скрипт в 90 строку файла jquery.chocolat.js

```
settings.container.append('<div id="Choco_overlay"></div><div id="Choco_content"><div id="Choco_close"></div><div id="Choco_loading"></div><div id="Choco_container_photo"><img id="Choco_bigImage" src="" /></div><div id="Choco_container_description"><span id="Choco_container_title"></span><span id="Choco_container_via"></span></div><div id="Choco_left_arrow" class="Choco_arrows"></div><div id="Choco_right_arrow" class="Choco_arrows"></div></div>');
```

Но в итоге плагин просто переставал работать
заранее спасибо

Comment: В чем проблема написать свой кастомный класс, и добавить на него стили при наведении. Сторонние библиотеки лучше не переписывать, мало ли эту же библиотеку будете использовать для еще одного поп-апа, а там зум не нужен будет.

Comment: Так же проверьте опцию в js
allowZoom: true
Она по дефолту тру, но мало ли изменили на фолс
И опции zoomedPaddingX и zoomedPaddingY
Так же не забудьте про наличие класса .chocolat-zoomable в вашей HMTL разметке